# Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/UnusedStub;

Tags: android, eclipse

I get the following errors in eclipse

```
Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/UnusedStub; 
XXX] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/UnusedStub;
```

Any Ideas to fix this?

Comment: You have conflicting dependencies. You are using two different versions of the same dependency.

Comment: how can I fix it? Did you know which dependency is can be?

Answer (score 2):

you have linked and internal jar in libs folder and in the same time you have it as an external one.
clean your project, delete the internal jar and build it again it will work.